# CLI tools commands used by GParted and KDE Partition Manager under the hood

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted, partitionmanager

GParted and KDE Partition Manager use libparted for some tasks, but they use other command-line tools under the hood.

I want to reproduce a complex set of operations done with GParted or KDE Partition Manager by manually executing individual commands from the terminal. These operations involve resizing and moving partitions.

The problem is that the GParted log and the KDE Partition Manager log are not detailed enough, as they do not provide a detailed list of the commands used. They mainly indicate "what" operations were performed but not "how."

Is it possible to know how every task is performed by GParted or KDE Partition Manager so I can manually re-execute the same tasks from the terminal?

*I'm not asking for a tutorial for `fdisk`, `cfdisk`, `sfdisk`, `parted` or similar.* **I'm asking if it is possible to automatically have the list of commands executed by GParted or KDE Partition Manager (assuming all their operations are performed invoking CLI tools under the hood).**

Answer (score 0):

More documentation can be found in the application help manual, and online at:
[running Gparted from the command line](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-run-from-cmd-line)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. Running GParted by launching it from the terminal is no help, as it does not log anything in the terminal.